# trying to fetch data from api and show it in react native flatlist and my code displays data in console log,but it didnt render in emulator

Tags: reactjs, native

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  Text,
  View,
  Alert,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Platform
} from "react-native";

class UserList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://000.000.0.000:0000/api/useraccount/user", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "auth-token": "my token"
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          // dataSource: JSON.parse(responseJson),
          dataSource: JSON.stringify(responseJson) //===>i think this is were problem
        });
        if (responseJson) {
          Alert.alert("Id is" + JSON.stringify(responseJson)); //==>this give me an alert
          console.log(responseJson);
        } else if (responseJson.error) {
          Alert.alert(responseJson.error);
        }
      })

      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 60,
          width: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "grey"
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Text> {item.name} </Text>}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default UserList;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  MainContainer: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    flex: 1,
    margin: 10,
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === "ios" ? 20 : 0
  },

  FlatListItemStyle: {
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    height: 44
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`FlatList` expects an array of objects. You are passing a string in `this.state.dataSource`. Also you don't need to parse it again with `JSON.parse` if you already resolve the response data with `response.json`.

Replace the following

```js
dataSource: JSON.stringify(responseJson)
```

with

```js
dataSource: responseJson
```

Be sure that responseJson is a array.

Comment: at first i had used response json ,but it doent get worked for me and after using stringify method i managed to display it in alert message

Answer (score 0):

finally found the solution...

Instead of flatlist , used list view to render the details...

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use flatlist instead of listview in terms when you have large quantities of data the data is displayed accordingly when the user swipes down looking for more information